# How to fix "org.apache.spark.shuffle.FetchFailedException: Failed to connect" in NetworkWordCount Spark Streaming application?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I try submit example Apache Spark Streaming application:

```
/opt/spark/bin/spark-submit --class org.apache.spark.examples.streaming.NetworkWordCount --deploy-mode cluster --master yarn --driver-memory 2g --executor-memory 2g /opt/spark/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.0.0.jar 172.29.74.68 9999
```

As parameters I type master IP and local port (in another console is running: `nc -lk 9999`).

And always I get error:

```
WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 50, iws1): FetchFailed(BlockManagerId(2, iws2, 41569), shuffleId=0, mapId=19, reduceId=0, message=
org.apache.spark.shuffle.FetchFailedException: Failed to connect to iws2/172.29.77.40:41569
    at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.throwFetchFailedException(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:357)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.next(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:332)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.next(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:54)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:434)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.CompletionIterator.hasNext(CompletionIterator.scala:32)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalAppendOnlyMap.insertAll(ExternalAppendOnlyMap.scala:154)
    at org.apache.spark.Aggregator.combineCombinersByKey(Aggregator.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.BlockStoreShuffleReader.read(BlockStoreShuffleReader.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.ShuffledRDD.compute(ShuffledRDD.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to iws2/172.29.77.40:41569
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:228)
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:179)
    at org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService$$anon$1.createAndStart(NettyBlockTransferService.scala:96)
    at org.apache.spark.network.shuffle.RetryingBlockFetcher.fetchAllOutstanding(RetryingBlockFetcher.java:140)
    at org.apache.spark.network.shuffle.RetryingBlockFetcher.access$200(RetryingBlockFetcher.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.network.shuffle.RetryingBlockFetcher$1.run(RetryingBlockFetcher.java:170)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: iws2/172.29.77.40:41569
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:224)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:289)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:528)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
    ... 1 more
```

[Full log here](http://wklej.org/id/2813687/?hl=logtalk)

Example "HdfsWordCount" works correctly. Other "non-streaming" application also.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution was to add `StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY_SER` to `socketTextStream` method, change `spark-defaults.conf` (as below) and increase hardware resources in `yarn-site.xml` file.

**spark-defaults.conf**

```
spark.core.connection.ack.wait.timeout 600s
spark.default.parallelism 4
spark.driver.memory 6g
spark.executor.memory 10g
spark.cores.max 4
spark.executor.cores 2
```

Comment: is there a guide where to find an appropriate combination of these spark parameters and those in yarn-site.xml?

Answer (score 0):

If you have many small files... in one partition
Your SparkJOB will be Fail 
`Exception“org.apache.spark.shuffle.FetchFailedException: Failed to connect”`

You need merge files in partition..

```
(example)
[AS-IS]
/yyyy=2019/a.txt
/yyyy=2019/b.txt
/yyyy=2019/c.txt
[TO-BE]
/yyyy=2019/merged.txt
```

---

if you have merged files in one partition,
Your SparkJOB will be success!
Good luck