# Spark Failure : Caused by: org.apache.spark.shuffle.FetchFailedException: Too large frame: 5454002341

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hadoop-yarn

I am generating a hierarchy for a table determining the parent child.

Below is the configuration used, even after getting the error with regards to the too large frame:

#### Spark properties

```
--conf spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=1024mb \
--conf yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb=12288mb \
--driver-memory 32g \
--driver-cores  8 \
--executor-cores 32 \
--num-executors 8 \
--executor-memory 256g \
--conf spark.maxRemoteBlockSizeFetchToMem=15g
```

---

```scala
import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger};
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, SparkSession};
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._;
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions._;

lazy val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder.enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate();

import spark.implicits._;

val hiveEmp: DataFrame = sparkSession.sql("select * from db.employee");
hiveEmp.repartition(300);
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._;

val nestedLevel = 3;

val empHierarchy = (1 to nestedLevel).foldLeft(hiveEmp.as("wd0")) { (wDf, i) =>
  val j = i - 1
  wDf.join(hiveEmp.as(s"wd$i"), col(s"wd$j.parent_id".trim) === col(s"wd$i.id".trim), "left_outer")
}.select(
  col("wd0.id") :: col("wd0.parent_id") ::
  col("wd0.amount").as("amount") :: col("wd0.payment_id").as("payment_id") :: (
    (1 to nestedLevel).toList.map(i => col(s"wd$i.amount").as(s"amount_$i")) :::
    (1 to nestedLevel).toList.map(i => col(s"wd$i.payment_id").as(s"payment_id_$i"))

  ): _*);

empHierarchy.write.saveAsTable("employee4");
```

#### Error

```
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows
   at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:204)
   at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1$$anonfun$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:129)
   at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1$$anonfun$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:128)
   at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
   at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
   at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:322)
   ... 3 more
Caused by: org.apache.spark.shuffle.FetchFailedException: Too large frame: 5454002341
   at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.throwFetchFailedException(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:361)
   at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.next(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:336)
```

Comment: let me know the no of cores in a single node?

Comment: 128 cores per machine, 200 node , 512 gb RAM on each node

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39268624/how-to-fix-org-apache-spark-shuffle-fetchfailedexception-failed-to-connect-in/58918235#58918235

Answer (score 8):

use this spark config, spark.maxRemoteBlockSizeFetchToMem < 2g

Since there is lot of issues with> 2G partition (cannot shuffle, cannot cache on disk), Hence it is throwing failedfetchedexception too large data frame.

Comment: this is totally safe first step for this issue. spark.maxRemoteBlockSizeFetchToMem < 2g and same it has got resolved to me.

Comment: This config fix was added to spark in May 2018. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-19659

Answer (score 7):

Suresh is right. Here's a better documented & formatted version of his answer with some useful background info:

- [bug report](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-5928) (link to the fix is at the very bottom)
- [fix](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-19659) (fixed as of 2.2.0 - already mentioned by Jared)
- [change of config's default value](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-24297) (changed as of 2.4.0)

If you're on a version 2.2.x or 2.3.x, you can achieve the same effect by setting the value of the config to `Int.MaxValue - 512`, i.e. by setting `spark.maxRemoteBlockSizeFetchToMem=2147483135`. See here for the [default value](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/internal/config/package.scala#L818) used as of September 2019.

Answer (score 4):

This means that size of your dataset partitions is enormous. You need to repartition your dataset to more partitions.

you can do this using,

```
df.repartition(n)
```

Here, `n` is dependent on the size of your dataset.

Comment: hiveEmp.repartition(300);
 Already have done the same, the same is mentioned over the code.

Comment: on this empHierarchy

Answer (score 2):

Got the exact same error when trying to Backfill a few years of Data. Turns out, its because your partitions are of size > 2gb.

1. You can either Bump up the number of partitions (using repartition()) so that your partitions are under 2GB. (Keep your partitions close to 128mb to 256mb i.e. close to the HDFS Block size)
2. Or you can bump up the shuffle limit to > 2GB as mentioned above. (Avoid it). Also, partitions with large amount of data will result in **tasks** that take a long time to finish.

Note: **repartition(n)** will result in **n** part files per partition during write to s3/hdfs.

Read this for more info:
http://www.russellspitzer.com/2018/05/10/SparkPartitions/

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing the same issue while I was working on a ~ 700GB dataset. Decreasing `spark.maxRemoteBlockSizeFetchToMem` didn't help in my case. In addition, I wasn't able to increase the amount of partitions.

Doing the following worked for me:

1. Increasing `spark.network.timeout` (default value is 120 seconds in Spark 2.3) which is affecting the following:

```
spark.core.connection.ack.wait.timeout
spark.storage.blockManagerSlaveTimeoutMs
spark.shuffle.io.connectionTimeout
spark.rpc.askTimeout
spark.rpc.lookupTimeout
```

2. Setting `spark.network.timeout=600s` (default is 120s in Spark 2.3)
3. Setting `spark.io.compression.lz4.blockSize=512k` (default is 32k in Spark 2.3)
4. Setting `spark.shuffle.file.buffer=1024k`(default is 32k in Spark 2.3)

Answer (score 0):

The below config worked for me.

1. keep spark.sql.shuffle.partitions and spark.default.parallelism same number
2. spark.maxRemoteBlockSizeFetchToMem <2GB
3. spark.shuffle.spill.compress and spark.shuffle.compress to "true..

   "spark.maxRemoteBlockSizeFetchToMem": "2147483135",
   "spark.sql.shuffle.partitions": "3000",
   "spark.default.parallelism": "3000",
   "spark.shuffle.spill.compress": "true",
   "spark.shuffle.compress": "true"