# Reproduce Too large frame exception in spark

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, apache-spark-sql

When writing spark application I often encounter the too large frame exception. To find a way of dealing with the issue I need to be able to reproduce the exception in Zeppelin or spark shell, without having to wait multiple hours.

I've already tried to create a dataframe of random ints and then `repartition(1).show` but either it returned a result or the driver did not respond anymore.

I also know this issue has a lot to do with data skew, but independently of the data i need to reproduce the exception.

Can you help me to reproduce the Exception? Here is an example:

```
org.apache.spark.shuffle.FetchFailedException: Too large frame: 2222736257
    at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.throwFetchFailedException(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:528)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.next(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:459)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.next(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:62)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spark Failure : Caused by: org.apache.spark.shuffle.FetchFailedException: Too large frame: 5454002341](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51278275/spark-failure-caused-by-org-apache-spark-shuffle-fetchfailedexception-too-la)

Comment: This is not a duplicate... I am not looking for a solution for the exception. I need the code to efficiently reproduce the exception without having to wait for hours. So far I could not do it on my own